# multiple upload file issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I have created an `add file upload function` and `multiple file upload function`.

`Add function` is working fine, but `Edit function` is not working.

After submitting the `EDIT` form, the *OLD VALUES* are not saved in the database.

The file is saved in some other folder.

Kindly help.

this is my code:controller file:

```
if(isset($_POST['additionalimage_exists']) && $_POST['additionalimage_exists'] != ''){
    $temp_image = $_POST['additionalimage_exists'];
    //echo $temp_image;die;

    if(isset($_FILES['additional_images']['name']) && $_FILES['additional_images']['name'] != ""){
      $errors= array();
      $additional_eventimages = $_FILES['additional_images']['name'];

      foreach($_FILES['additional_images']['name'] as $key => $tmpName) {


      $additionalimages = $_FILES['additional_images']['name'][$key];
      $file_type = $_FILES['additional_images']['type'][$key];
      $file_size = $_FILES['additional_images']['size'][$key];
      $file_tmp  = $_FILES['additional_images']['tmp_name'][$key];

      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/events/".$additionalimages);
    }

}
  else
    {
      $additional_eventimages = $temp_image;
    }
}
```

view File:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="additional-image">Additional Images</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="additional_images[]" value="<?php echo $additional_images;?>" multiple="multiple">
            <input type="hidden" name="additionalimage_exists" value="<?php echo $additional_images;?>" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" placeholder="Enter Image Text" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
            <div>
                <?php echo $additional_images;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show error

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
            if(isset($_FILES['additional_images']['name']) && $_FILES['additional_images']['name'] != ""){
              $errors= array();
              $additional_eventimages = $_FILES['additional_images']['name'];

              foreach($_FILES['additional_images']['name'] as $key => $tmpName) {


              $additionalimages = $_FILES['additional_images']['name'][$key];
              $file_type = $_FILES['additional_images']['type'][$key];
              $file_size = $_FILES['additional_images']['size'][$key];
              $file_tmp  = $_FILES['additional_images']['tmp_name'][$key];

              move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/events/".$additionalimages);

            } else if(isset($_POST['additionalimage_exists']) && $_POST['additionalimage_exists'] != ''){
      $additional_eventimages = $_POST['additionalimage_exists'];

    } else {
              $additional_eventimages = "";
            }
```